# java.io.exception Cannot run program "python"

Tags: java, python, apache-storm

I'm trying to run wordcount topology on apache storm via command line in ubuntu and it is using multiland property to split words from sentences with a program written in python. 
I've set the classpath of the multilang dir in **.bashrc** file but still at the time of execution it is giving error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when launching multilang subprocess
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "/tmp/eaf0b6b3-67c1-4f89-b3d8-23edada49b04/supervisor/stormdist/word-count-1-1414559082/resources"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, I was submitting jar to storm but the cluster it contain was Local and hence the classpath was not working while uploading jar to storm, I re modified the code and change the local cluster to storm cluster and then It was uploaded successfully to storm, along this I have also included the classpath of multilang folder in the eclipse ide itself instead of creating it in .bashrc file.

Answer (score -1):

The python installed in the system may have its default path, such as /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. Python modules may have different paths.

Do not fully override $PATH environment variable in **.bashrc**.

Or you can set the execution bit of the Python script you would like to run, and call the script as a normal program in storm.

Comment: These settings have already being done, The answer need more advancement.